# Ugly Triple Indirection: Extensible Buffer Management Struct

Tags: c, parsing, avr, readability

I'm currently trying to build a string parser for an AVR based stepper motor controller. The idea is to observe some input string over UART, then breaking apart this string into several sub-buffers that will eventually find their way into a set of motor control behaviors. Considering the following delimiters:

'<' - START 
'%' - CHANGE BUFFER 
'>' - STOP 
'A' - Clockwise 
'B' - Counterclockwise

I would take in a somewhat arbitrarily wide string that looks something like <1234A%7743B> and turn that into "1234 steps clockwise on motor 1, 7743 steps counterclockwise on motor B".

So far, I've come up with the following solution

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define TARGET 12

typedef struct 
{
    uint8_t STRING_SEL;

    char  X    [32]; // buffer X
    char  Y    [32]; // buffer Y
    uint8_t  iX; // buffer X iterator
    uint8_t  iY; // buffer Y iterator
    uint8_t  PTR_CTR;

    char* Xptr; // pointer to buffer X
    char* Yptr; // pointer to buffer Y

    uint8_t * iXptr; // pointer to buffer X iterator
    uint8_t * iYptr; // pointer to buffer Y iterator

    char ** PTR_ARR [2];   //pointer to array of buffer initial value pointers
    uint8_t ** CTR_ARR[2]; //pointer to array of buffer iterator pointers

} parser_manager;

static parser_manager mgr =  {
                              .STRING_SEL = 0,
                              .X          = {[0 ... 31] = 0},
                              .Y          = {[0 ... 31] = 0},
                              .iX         = 0,
                              .iY         = 0,
                              .PTR_CTR    = 0,
                              .Xptr       = &mgr.X[0],
                              .Yptr       = &mgr.Y[0],
                              .iXptr      = &mgr.iX,
                              .iYptr      = &mgr.iY,
                              .PTR_ARR    = {&mgr.Xptr, &mgr.Yptr},
                              .CTR_ARR    = {&mgr.iXptr, &mgr.iYptr}
                             };
```

Which lands me in three star programming hell, and lends itself to yucky member accesses like:

```c
char EXPECT_CHAR = *(*(*(mgr.PTR_ARR + mgr.PTR_CTR)) + (***(mgr.CTR_ARR + mgr.PTR_CTR)));
(mgr.Y[TARGET] == EXPECT_CHAR) ? printf("1\n") : printf("0\n");
```

So why do something this ugly? I went about this with the rationale that while parsing through the incoming characters, I would increment PTR_CTR for every '%' character, thus switching iterators and buffers cleanly. I could then extend this out for some N number of motors by adding the buffers and pointers to the struct, then widening the PTR and CTR arrays.

I can see that I could save myself a level of indirection with the counter array, as it doesn't need to be an array of double pointers.

This feels like an extremely inelegant way of going about this problem. How do I make this process cleaner? My only thought so far is to move to fixed width packets, nixing the need for this faux-dynamism.

Comment: 1) learn how [strtok()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strtok.htm) could help to parse a string with delimiter into an array. 2) Read a [c book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and learn about pointer and dereferencing. The ugliness has nothing to do about the readability but the understanding of the c pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `X` and `Y` as member of structure `parser_manager`:

```
    char  X    [32]; // buffer X
    char  Y    [32]; // buffer Y
```

You have also mentioned

> *I could then extend this out for some N number of motors by adding the buffers and pointers to the struct, then widening the PTR and CTR arrays.*

How are you planning to do it? (by adding more members like `X` and `Y` in `parser_manager` structure!)

Better to create a different structure having member `X` and `Y`. Take a pointer of that structure in `parser_manager` structure so that you can extend it by reallocating memory. With this, you can do away with multiple level of indirection's when accessing `X` and `Y` buffers.

Sample code for demonstration purpose:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    char X[32];
    char Y[32];
} buffers;

typedef struct {
    buffers * ptr_x_y;
    int numele;   // to keep track of number of elements
} parser_manager;

int main (void)
{
    parser_manager mgr = {NULL, 0};

    mgr.numele = 1;
    mgr.ptr_x_y = malloc (sizeof (buffers) * mgr.numele);
    if (!mgr.ptr_x_y) {
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    strcpy (mgr.ptr_x_y[0].X, "DUMMY_X1");
    strcpy (mgr.ptr_x_y[0].Y, "DUMMY_Y1");
    printf ("%s, %s\n", mgr.ptr_x_y[0].X, mgr.ptr_x_y[0].Y);
    
    mgr.numele = 2;
    buffers * temp;
    mgr.ptr_x_y = realloc (temp = mgr.ptr_x_y, mgr.numele * sizeof (buffers));
    if (!mgr.ptr_x_y) {
        free (temp);
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    strcpy (mgr.ptr_x_y[1].X, "DUMMY_X2");
    strcpy (mgr.ptr_x_y[1].Y, "DUMMY_Y2");
    printf ("%s, %s\n", mgr.ptr_x_y[0].X, mgr.ptr_x_y[0].Y);
    printf ("%s, %s\n", mgr.ptr_x_y[1].X, mgr.ptr_x_y[1].Y);
    
    // free dynamically allocted memory
    
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
DUMMY_X1, DUMMY_Y1
DUMMY_X1, DUMMY_Y1
DUMMY_X2, DUMMY_Y2
```

`iX` and `iY` are iterators of buffer `X` and `Y`, therefore you can make them  member of `buffers` structure as well.

If for some reason, you cannot use dynamic memory allocation functions `malloc` or `realloc`, then you can do:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_BUFFERS 10

typedef struct {
    char X[32];
    char Y[32];
} buffers;

typedef struct {
    buffers * ptr_x_y[MAX_BUFFERS];
    int numele;   // to keep track of number of elements
} parser_manager;

int main (void)
{
    parser_manager mgr = {{NULL}, 0};
    
    buffers buf1 = {.X = "DUMMY_X1", .Y = "DUMMY_Y1"};
    
    mgr.numele = 1;
    mgr.ptr_x_y[0] = &buf1;
    
    printf ("%s, %s\n", mgr.ptr_x_y[0]->X, mgr.ptr_x_y[0]->Y);    

    buffers buf2 = {.X = "DUMMY_X2", .Y = "DUMMY_Y2"};
    
    mgr.numele = 2;
    mgr.ptr_x_y[1] = &buf2;
    
    printf ("%s, %s\n", mgr.ptr_x_y[1]->X, mgr.ptr_x_y[1]->Y);
   
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
DUMMY_X1, DUMMY_Y1
DUMMY_X2, DUMMY_Y2
```

Comment: Thank you, this was a comprehensive response. I communicated poorly, where X and Y would act as buffers for two motors, but the logic is the same regardless. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Without going down to the implementatio details, the implementatio may become more comprehensible when you gather stuff belongong to the same butter in one object, like:

```cpp
typedef struct
{
    char buf[32]; // Buffer
    uint8_t  it;  // Buffer iterator
    char ** PTR_ARR;    //pointer to array of buffer initial value pointers
    uint8_t ** CTR_ARR; //pointer to array of buffer iterator pointers
    ...
} motor_t

#define N_MOTORS 2

motor_t motors[N_MOTORS];
```

And then have a function that takes a `motor_t*` pointer to accomplish specific tasks like: filling the buffer, mapping values to motor behaviour, etc.

`PTR_ARR` and `CTR_ARR` still look like hack though, and that there is a more straight forward data structure.